# Is there a way to tell Handlebars to access a default path from an object if it is not explicitly specified?

Tags: handlebars.js

If path is not specified in Handlebars template for an object type data source it will display “[object Object]”. Instead, I wanna achieve the following result.

Template:

```html
<div>
    {{user}}
<div/>
```

Data:

```json
{
  "user": { "title": "John Somebody" }
}
```

Result:

```
<div>
    John Somebody
<div/>
```

#### What's going on here?

In case a path is not specified, `Handlebars` will take a "default path" from an object if it is an object, otherwise puts there an empty string.
Is there a way to accomplish that using helpers or some other custom stuff?
Also, I wanna avoid additional keywords in template HTML as much as possible.

Comment: Why?! What is excessive about `{{ user.title }}`?

Comment: I’am just interested in an actual possibility to do such thing.